# Relation between Jordan canonical form and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

After seeing a couple of example Jordan canonical forms, I have the following proposition:

> The largest block of an eigenvalue is equal to the power of that factor in the minimal polynomial.

Is this true? Also, can you have multiple blocks for a single eigenvalue? I think so (hence the wording of "largest"). Lastly, is this "largest" block always attained, or is it just an upper bound?

EDIT: Can anyone reference me to a good book or online lecture notes for Jordan canonical forms or how to solve problems exploiting their properties?

Comment: This is true. To see it, just take the characteristic polynomial of a Jordan canonical form. And of course you can have multiple blocks for one eigenvalue. Here you are $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$